# Mutliple EditoFor of the same model property in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
<div id="band" class="auth-form-body" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    Band name<br/>              
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProfileName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-block form-control-lg", @style = "width: 100%;" } })
</div>
<div id="musician" class="auth-form-body" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    Musician name<br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProfileName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-block form-control-lg", @style = "width: 100%;" } })
</p>
</div>
```

When I enter a value for Band name, It works. The ProfileName-property get's a value. But when I enter a value for Musician Name, the ProfileName-property get's a null value.

Why does this not work and how can I solve this?

Comment: You cannot have 2 for controls for the same property (not only are your creating invalid html, only the value of the first input will ever be bound to the property. Its not clear what your wanting to do here. You can always have 2 properties in the model (say `BandName` and `MusicianName`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one EditorFor for the same property.But having two properties in the model is a bad practice too.

To get around these issues there is a design pattern called MVVM (Model View ViewModel). Check MVVM tutorial on tutorialspoint.